# New remote-controlled ceiling fan doesn't respond to wall switch

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

I replaced a ceiling fan in my bedroom that no longer worked. I didn't pay attention to the wiring when removing the old fan but diligently followed the instructions. The new fan has a light kit and remote kit and it all works perfectly except they are no longer controlled by the light switch.

There is a double switch in the bedroom. The right switch controls a lamp next to the bed. The left switch previously controlled the ceiling fan light (the fan itself never worked when I bought the home). I can turn everything off with the remote but want to be able to walk into the room and turn on the ceiling fan and/or light with the wall switch like I used to.

I think I may have missed a wire. There is a red, black, white, and green all coming out of the ceiling box but after following the directions I didn't connect the red wire to anything so I capped it off. Should this have been connected with the black wire to the ceiling fan black wire?

Comment: the red may be a extra hot incase an additional switch was added

Comment: The model number of the fan, or a picture of the wiring diagram included in the manual, would be helpful.

Comment: Can you add the model number of the fan, and photos of the insides of the boxes?

Answer (score 1):

If the fan has a remote module, it's designed to be controlled by the remote. You can usually bypass or eliminate the remote module, but it's usually not possible to control the fan from both the switch and remote.

You'll have to look in the switch box, to determine if the red wire is actually extra.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one switch you can't turn the fan **and** the light on and off individually.

You can turn on the power and let that control both of them at the same time. Or either the light or the fan but not both.

One of them will have to be turned on by the remote or a pull chain while the power is left on.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you'll need the check the wiring on the switch but at a guess the red wire is the one attached to the switch and the black is always hot and should be wired to just the fan check this with a multimeter to be safe. red and black are the primary wires that carry current

I know at least on my fan there are 4 wires on the fan itself a ground (green/bare) a neutral (white) and 2 others that are the hot wires for the fan and light.